# insertion of records automatically in database using scheduler

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2007

how is it possible to insert records automatically in database when due date expired using timer ? i want insert records in MS Access database using VB.NET....
actually i want insertion of records of hostelers in due Charges table who did not paid the fees at due date...
i want something like if any hosteler due date expired on 15 /oct/ 2013 then record should be automatically inserted in due charges table....

i tried timer_tick event but it was inserting so many duplicate records
how can i use scheduler in vb.net ?

Comment: So you had the right general idea and didn't get all the details correct?

Comment: can u suggest me some ideas how is it possible using sql query ?

Comment: please someone help or give me some basic ideas :(

Comment: i need basic ideas how can i perform it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can i use scheduler in vb.net ?

There is some sample code available [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSTaskScheduler-2f70d723). It is a C# example, but it should give you some idea of how you might manipulate Scheduled Tasks from a VB.NET app.

Comment: tnX...it is really useful